# Simple String Comparison In Javascript Do Not Work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to compare two passwords, **New Password** and **Confirm New Password**, this should very simple and straight forward.

But i don't know why this isn't working. **Exhausted**

```
if (newpassword !== confnewpassword) {
    console.log('New:"'+newPassword+'" and Conf:"'+confnewpassword+'" Password Do Not Match');

}else{
    //some server code
}
```

Also Tried

```
if (newpassword === confnewpassword) {
    //Some Server Code
}else{
    console.log('New:"'+newPassword+'" and Conf:"'+confnewpassword+'" Password Do Not Match');
}
```

Console Output is `New:"timecapsule7" and Conf:"timecapsule7" Password Do Not Match`

Comment: `newPassword`  and `newpassword` are not the same. You are logging the former on your console.

Comment: ah, nice catch... didn't see the typo

Comment: Sorry! was banging my head. should i delete question?

Comment: could your new and old password be pointing to same string object!!?

Comment: @NomanAli Yeah, since it was a typo. I won't likely help any future readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because your `newpassword` is `undefined`.  your string is in `newPassword`(check the **camelCase**). Javascript don't work by that way.

Any good editor or some linting would have saved you from this situation.

Answer (score 1):

In your if statement your using "newpassword" with a lowercase p but in your log you're using "newPassword" with a capital "P". Not sure if that fixes it.

Answer (score -1):

This can only mean one thing: Since you use Triple equals, the two variables are not of the same type. When you concatenate them into a string, javascript will automatically run the .toStrgin() function which will make them look as if they were the same.

EDIT:

Actually, there is a typo in the variable names... `newPassword` and `newpassword` are not the same. Check your capitals

Comment: Its a TYPO, So you should delete the answer and vote to close the OP